# How do I enter codes on the iOS version of Fez?

Tags: ios, fez

In the new (December 2017) iOS version of *Fez*, how do I use the virtual controls on the iPhone to input the many codes needed to open new areas and doors?

Answer (score 1):

It should work the same as the other releases, except that you swipe the screen to rotate the world (since iPhones have no "trigger" buttons).